# Can Heroku edit files?

Tags: python, git, heroku

I have an app deployed on Heroku that reads a line from a file, then is supposed to delete that line in the file and add that line to a different file. If all the necessary files are in the Heroku git repo and assuming the code runs without any errors, will the files be changed?

Comment: Have you _tried it_?

Comment: I have tried it but I don't have any way of viewing the file since Heroku doesn't have a visual interface/file viewer, so I can't tell if it has been changed.

Comment: Programmers have to try things out all the time. Look for a way to do that. For example: Add a page that shows the contents of the file. Modify the file. Verify that it was changed. Restart your Dyno. Check to see if your changes persist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes made directly to the filesystem on Heroku dynos will be lost whenever your dyno restarts. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting):

> Dynos are also restarted (cycled) at least once per day to help maintain the health of applications running on Heroku. Any changes to the local filesystem [will be deleted](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). The cycling happens once every 24 hours (plus up to 216 random minutes, to prevent every dyno for an application from restarting at the same time).

Instead of writing to a file on the filesystem you should consider using a database. Heroku [provides a PostgreSQL service](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql), but there are many [other options](https://elements.heroku.com/addons).

If for some reason you really do need to store a file, Heroku [recommends using something like Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).

Comment: I know that local changes are lost when the dynos restart but if the file is stored in the Heroku git repo does it count as local, and do changes persist through dyno cycles?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. You wouldn't be editing a file "stored in the Heroku git repo", you'd be editing a file in a [slug](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler).